# How to arrange images in a div evenly without breaking their aspect ratio

Tags: css, position

I think I'll best explain myself when I show my failed attempts:

## Attempt 1. `margin auto`

```css
div {
    height: 50px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

div > img {
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/U%2B25C9.svg"/>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/U%2B25C9.svg"/>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/U%2B25C9.svg"/>
</div>
```

See? I have a `div` and I want to arrange these circles in this `div` evenly. Sadly, with the current approach, they won't sit next to each other but rather, they're stacking themselves in a pillar.

## Attempt 2. `flex`

```css
div {
    height: 50px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
}

div > img {
    height: 100%;
    flex: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/U%2B25C9.svg"/>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/U%2B25C9.svg"/>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/U%2B25C9.svg"/>
</div>
```

Now the circles are evenly arranged BUT the aspect ratio is screwed.

No, I cant just set `width` to the desired value, because 1) it doesn't seem to be working 2) even if it was working, the height of the `div` is specified in percentages of the enclosing container (here I specified it in `px` for the sake of simplicity) so I don't know which value to put there

Any way to distribute the circles evenly in the div without breaking aspect ratio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost good with the flexbox approach. Don't make the element growing so don't set flex to auto which will set `flex-grow:1`

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

div>img {
  height: 100%;
  /*Or margin:auto instead of justify-content: space-around*/
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/U%2B25C9.svg" />
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/U%2B25C9.svg" />
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a6/U%2B25C9.svg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
    height: 50px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
}

div > img {
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Just use flex but don't do flex: auto on the imgs and it works fine